# spark collect as Array[T] and not as Array[Row] from data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I can collect a column like this using the RDD API.

```
df.map(r => r.getAs[String]("column")).collect
```

However, as I am initially using a Dataset I rather would like to not switch the API level. A simple `df.select("column).collect` returns an `Array[Row]` where the `.flatten` operator no longer works.
How can I collect to `Array[T e.g. String]` directly?

Comment: Have you tried `df.select("column).as[String].collect`? Writing from memory, if works I'll post normal answer :)

Comment: Array of the type of the selected column e.g. string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Datasets ( Spark version >= 2.0.0 ), you just need to convert the dataframe to dataset and then collect it.

```
df.select("column").as[String].collect()
```

would return you an Array[String]

Comment: nice. That works fine. But why isn't the type inferred from the schema of the dataset automatically?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler yes and not :) It is inferred, but it will be Row[String], because in select you can put many column names. Converter will automatically convert to String